# hello guys i am using django but it`s not loading JavaScript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

```
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/lib/%40fortawesome/all.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/lib/stickyfilljs/stickyfill.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/lib/sticky-kit/sticky-kit.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/lib/is_js/is.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/lib/lodash/lodash.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/lib/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.js' %}"></script>

<script src="{% static 'assets/lib/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/lib/plyr/plyr.polyfilled.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/lib/select2/select2.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/theme.min.js' %}"></script>
```

even in settings i have added this:
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),

]

Comment: have you added `{% load static %}` in top of your html?

Answer (score 0):

in main project urls.py files include

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

and template include `{% load static %}`